# Driver in Windows 10 S mode returns "A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer."

Tags: windows-10, certificate, driver, desktop-bridge

I have a driver that is signed by my company and Microsoft as per MS guidelines for drivers in Windows 10. When I try to start this driver in Windows 10 S mode returns "A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer." and never starts.

However, this same driver works fine in same machine out of S mode (regular Windows 10 Home out of S mode).

I verified the windows cert store as the following question and there is no revoked keys related to my cert: [How to get sign my mini-filter driver for Windows 10 from Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403581/how-to-get-sign-my-mini-filter-driver-for-windows-10-from-microsoft)

What can prevent my driver works fine (with such an error) in S mode vs out of it?

Answer (score 0):

> I verified the windows cert store...

Revocation is done by the issuer of the certificate, not in the store.

Revocation checking is done either via

a) **Certificate Revocation List** (CRL), a file that is downloadable from it's *Certificate revocation list Distribution Point* (CDP), which is an extension in the certificate:

[image: CDP Extension]

b) **Online Certificate Status Protocol** (OCSP), which is an extension in the certificate:

[image]

The [DigiCert util](https://www.digicert.com/util/) can be used to check the revocation status:

Here are some options to check the revocation status:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pki/2006/11/30/basic-crl-checking-with-certutil/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f78d7b9e-8911-4149-9f88-d047a50e2cff/how-can-i-verify-that-my-ocsp-server-is-working
- https://certificate.revocationcheck.com/
- https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-test-revocation-status.htm

If the certificate is revoked you need to get a new one and sign the driver again.

> It works in *normal mode*

Is the [driver signature enforcement](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-do-i-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-win/a53ec7ca-bdd3-4f39-a3af-3bd92336d248) disabled on the *not in s-mode* installation?