# Signed Driver rejected by Windows 10

Tags: windows, driver, hardware, code-signing

I have a Windows kernel driver that I have signed with a DigiCert EV code signing certificate. Unfortunately, Windows 10 rejects the file even though it is signed by me and Microsoft.

This is what I did:

I submitted the package to the Windows Partner Center as a hardware submission, and it was successfully signed by Microsoft. I selected every listed version of Windows that was not ARM based, for what signatures I was requesting.

I run this command to confirm that the driver is signed well enough for Windows to accept it:

**signtool verify gsllc.sys**

It gives the following response:

**SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.**

**Number of errors: 1**

When I attempt to load the driver into Windows 10, current version, the event log shows the following error:

The gsllc service failed to start due to the following error:
A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer.

My certificate is only days old, and it hasn't been revoked according to DigiCert.

Anybody have any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Try checking the details of the revocation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57640769/179634

Comment: Just checked it with the DigiCert Utility. It passed the revocation check.

Comment: Try running `signtool verify /v /debug gsllc.sys` to see if it gives you any additional details.

Comment: Luke, it gave a complete chain of trust for both my company's cert and the timestamp cert, but then it just gave the same error message. No additional details.

Comment: I've contacted DigiCert, and was lucky that someone picked up on the weekend. The support technician couldn't figure it out either. We tried installing the DigiCert intermediate and root certs into my local machine store and my personal store to no avail. He said everything looks OK with my certificate, so he's escalating it to their development team.